# How to extract JSON value from a list and render it in a django model form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to render a Django model form using the below model. The problem is one of the model field is a JSONField. This is a list of length 1 having some JSON data. When I render the model form, the `number` field renders the list without any issues. But I want to extract the `phone` value from the JSON inside the list and render it. I have tried extracting it in the template but it is not working as intended.

How can I extract the `phone` value from the JSON and render it in the form? As example, when I render the data for id 1 using my view, I should see 'Client_1' in the name field and '1234567890' in the number field.

I am using Django 3.1 and using Django Crispy Forms to render the model form.

Data as seen client table in db:

```
id  name        number
1   Client_1    [{'type': 'mobile', 'phone': '1234567890'}]
2   Client_2    [{'type': 'mobile', 'phone': '3334445555'}]
3   Client_3    [{'type': 'mobile', 'phone': '9876543210'}]
```

*models.py:*

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    number = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

*forms.py:*

```
from .models import Client

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
```

clients.html template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.name | as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {% for item in form.number %}
                {{ item.0.phone | as_crispy_field }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

*views.py:*

```
def clients(request, pk):
    instance = Client.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = ClientForm(instance=instance)

    return render(request, 'clients.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add fields dynamically to your form, here is a working example :

```py
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, instance=None, **kwargs):
        super(ClientForm, self).__init__(*args, instance=instance, **kwargs)
        if instance:
            for index, obj in enumerate(instance.number):
                self.fields[f'phone_{index}'] = forms.CharField(initial=obj.get('phone', ''))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        for index, obj in enumerate(self.instance.number):
            obj['phone'] = self.cleaned_data.get(f'phone_{index}', '')
        return super(ClientForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['name']
```

Your template should then be :

```html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.name | as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.phone_0 | as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**NB** : If you alway store your phones in a list, you should set a default to your JsonField :

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    number = models.JSONField(default=list)
```

Comment: I tried the above __init__ and save methods in my form. But it still displays the list as shown in my question. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to update your template

Comment: sorry I got caught up with work. I will update my answer shortly. I am just curious. Does `{{ form.phone_1 | as_crispy_field }}` work for any ID? Or does the `form.phone_1` have to be made dynamic?

Comment: I can confirm that your method worked. Only one small change I had to do in the template was to change `{{ form.phone_1 | as_crispy_field }}` to `{{ form.phone_0 | as_crispy_field }}` based on the traceback error I received. After making this small update, it works perfectly. Thank you so much for looking into this. I honestly have no clue what the init method is doing though.. :-)

Comment: I actually found a scenario where the number field was blank. This caused an error. So to overcome this, I modified your __ini__ function a little bit:
`
if instance.number:
    for index, obj in enumerate(instance.number):
        self.fields[f'phone}'] = forms.CharField(initial=obj.get('phone', ''))
else:
    self.fields[f'phone'] = forms.CharField(initial='')
`